# How do I allocate a buffer with Ruby's Fiddle for use with Win32 functions such as SendMessage?

Tags: ruby, winapi, sendmessage, fiddle

The function signature for SendMessageW as per [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessagew):

```
LRESULT SendMessageW(
  [in] HWND   hWnd,
  [in] UINT   Msg,
  [in] WPARAM wParam,
  [in] LPARAM lParam
);
```

I wish to get the text in a window title/caption using the [WM_GETTEXT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-gettext) Msg.
The problem I am having is that LPARAM is a long int type, and using standard C, the char buffer could be cast to LPARAM, but using Ruby and Fiddle the calling convention is not so clear. I have tried:

```
captionText = String.new
User32::SendMessageW(hWnd, User32::WM_GETTEXT, bufLen, captionText)
```

which gives an implicit conversion from string to int error, and:

```
User32::SendMessageW(hWnd, User32::WM_GETTEXT, bufLen, captionText.to_i)
```

Which appears to do nothing.

I already have the window handle and length of the text from earlier calls, e.g:

```
hWnd = User32::FindWindow(<class name of window>, <window title>)
bufLen = User32::SendMessageW(hWnd, User32::WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0) + 1
```

I have defined the WinAPI functions in a manner similar to the examples here, and they work:

https://coder-question.com/cq-blog/432387?force_isolation=true

I am aware of the GetWindowText and GetWindowTextLength functions, however GetWindowTextLength is not working for child windows, so I've decided to try SendMessage instead.

Comment: You probably want to be using [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) instead anyway. If you need some incentive you should read [The secret life of GetWindowText](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030821-00/?p=42833) and [Why are the rules for GetWindowText so weird?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030904-00/?p=42663).

Comment: If you provide a runnable example I will help you. I have an idea how to do it, but I don't have time to figure out all the missing bits. Create a minimal example for let's say Notepad, and I will see if I can make it work.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This may not be ideal, however I got it working:
First I created a buffer:

    buf = Fiddle::Pointer.malloc(bufLen)

Then we can pass this buffer to SendMessage:

    bytesWritten = User32::SendMessage(hWnd, User32::WM_GETTEXT, bufLen, buf)

Then we can get a Ruby string:

    captionText = buf.to_s

I did have issues when using SendMessageW as naturally it contained UTF-16 encoded characters, which then cause subsequent problems with the .to_s conversion (null byte complaints)

I suppose using a Ruby string method that is encoding aware would be better!